# Consuming Restful api in Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I need to know how to consume RESTful api in UI.
And also I need to know can we use the api for the same app or we shall create new app to consume these api produced from REST. I have built a REST api in my project and I used the api in the same project with following code. But it didnt work.

RestClient.java

```
package com.spring.template;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.spring.model.Employee;

public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            final String base_url = "http://localhost:8080/SpringWebSevices/";
            Employee employee = restTemplate.getForObject(base_url, Employee.class, 200);
            System.out.println("Id:"+employee.getEmpid());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package com.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.spring.model.Employee;
import com.spring.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value ="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="application/json") 
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> employees() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        List<Employee> employee = employeeService.getEmployees();
        if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        headers.add("Number of records found:", String.valueOf(employee.size()));
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST , produces ="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
        headers.add("Added employee id:", String.valueOf(employee.getEmpid()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/edit/{id}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> editEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int empid,@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        Employee isExist = employeeService.getEmployee(empid);
        if(isExist == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
        employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        headers.add("Employee updated:", String.valueOf(employee.getEmpid()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee,headers,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/delete/{id}", method =RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int empid) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(empid);
        if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(empid);
        headers.add("Employee deleted:", String.valueOf(empid));
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee, headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

This is the error i got:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.spring.model.Employee out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: What exactly did not work? What is the behavior you are getting and what are you expecting? Also posting your spring controller could help.

Comment: Okay Will post controller too

Comment: You are trying to call the method mapped to "SpringWebSevices", but from what I can see no such mapping exists in your controller. As a rule of thumb, you can also open links in your browser to test your GET methods. So just going to "http://localhost:8080/SpringWebSevices/", in your browser, might give you some more insight.

Comment: SpringWebServices is the project name

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value ="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="application/json") ` This is the mapping

Comment: sorry, my bad. In that case it is most likely a deserialization issue. In that case you are returning List<Employee> and trying to assign it to a single Employee object.

Comment: Didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.spring.model.Employee out of START_ARRAY token`

This looks like your sending a list of `Employee` to some method that accepts a single `Employee` as a parameter. Possibilities:

- addEmployee
- editEmployee

Comment: So how to use it with GET?

Comment: If you want to return a List of objects, I think you are going to need to use this method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is returning `List<Employee>`, while you are trying to assign the result to a single Employee object in the line

```
Employee employee = restTemplate.getForObject(base_url, Employee.class, 200);
```

You are facing type incompatibilities, you could try

```
ResponseEntity<? extends ArrayList<Employee>> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(base_url, (Class<? extends ArrayList<Employee>)ArrayList.class, 200);
```

I haven't tested it yet but it should work.

Comment: I edited the answer in the meanwhile, did you try the edited version? (Aka as it now stands)